# What real-life examples of a Tridiagonal matrix are there?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

I've been looking into the Tridiagonal matrix algorithm. There's theory everywhere but not a lot of real-world applications and examples of tridiagonal matrices. I understand it is a pretty simple and must be found in plenty of places. I hoped that someone could give me a fun example here.

Thanks.

Comment: I know that they come up in differential equations and pdes.  For instance, the discrete analog of the one-dimensional wave equation with $0$ boundary conditions involves analyzing a tridiagonal matrix.  They're also important to the [QR-algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm)

Answer (score 3):

It's used in partial differential equations. One example is the heat equation. You end up with a [tridiagonal matrix.](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~gerry/class/ME448/notes/pdf/BTCS_slides.pdf) The heat equation is

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = k \frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}} \tag{1}$$

you use backward difference to approximate $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$

$$  \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\Big|_{t_{k} x_{i}} \approx  \frac{u_{i}^{k} - u_{i}^{k-1}}{\Delta t} \tag{2}$$

using central difference for $k \frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}} $

$$  \frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}\Big|_{t_{k},x_{i}} \approx \frac{u_{i-1}^{k} -2u_{i}^{k} + u_{i+1}^{k}}{\Delta x^{2}}  \tag{4}$$

this can be represented as a matrix

$$ \begin{bmatrix} a_{1} & b_{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ c_{2} & a_{2} & b_{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & c_{3} & a_{3} & b_{3} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & c_{nx-1} & a_{nx-1} & b_{nx-1} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & c_{nx} & a_{nx} \\\end{bmatrix} \tag{5}$$

if you read the document you use LU decomp to solve, there is a special form of the LU decomp for tridiagonal matrices.

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples in physics. Consider a linear chain of interacting particles, but the interaction is only to the nearest neighbor. You can write the Hamiltonian of this system as a tridiagonal matrix, with the kinetic energy on the diagonal and the interaction energy one element off the diagonal. You can map heat equation or waves to such a matrix as well.